# Why exception is not caught by my promise's catch clause?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, exception, promise, try-catch

I have this code, hoping to catch all exception during this async method. Somehow, an url exception happened but it was not caught by the catch clause. I have to add a try-catch block around it to catch that exception, don't know why, can someone explain?

```
public async transform(
  ): Promise {
   const {result} = this.processUrl(url).catch(error => error);
   return result;
}


private processUrl(url: string): Promise {
  const targetHostname = new URL(url).hostname; // exception thrown here invalid url something
  // do something else ...
  return Promise.resolve(targetHostname);
}
```

---

I was hoping tranform function will never throw exception, but when I provide an invalid url, processUrl method throws out an exception which somehow didn't get caught in the transform function.
I have to do this to catch it.

```
public async transform(
  ): Promise {
try {
   const {result} = this.processUrl(url).catch(error => error);
} catch(e) {
    // invalid url exception got caught
    return Promise.resolve(undefined);
}
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`processURL()` is not an `async` function.  Thus, it does not automatically return a promise and does not automatically catch exceptions and turn them into a rejected promise.

So, if an exception is thrown anywhere in `processURL()`, that exception just propagates upwards as a synchronous exception.  If you want to catch that synchronous exception yourself, you will need a try/catch in order to catch it.

Or, you could make `processURL()` an `async` function and then it will automatically catch any synchronous exceptions and turned them into a rejected promise that you could then catch with `.catch()` like this:

```
private async processUrl(url: string): Promise {
  const targetHostname = new URL(url).hostname; // exception thrown here invalid url something
  // do something else ...
  return Promise.resolve(targetHostname);
}
```

Or you could catch it manually:

```
private processUrl(url: string): Promise {
  try {
      const targetHostname = new URL(url).hostname; // exception thrown here invalid url something
      // do something else ...
      return Promise.resolve(targetHostname);
  } catch(e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
  }
}
```

You may also have an issue here:

```
const {result} = this.processUrl(url).catch(error => error);
```

Because your `processUrl()` function is set up to return a promise.  You need to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value out of that promise.  FYI, if `processUrl()` is actually entirely synchronous, then it is just complicating matters to make it return a promise when it could just return a value directly.